# GNOME desktop manager no longer opening, drop to console login screen

Tags: gnome, login, display, gdm

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell 5540.      Everything was working fine until I rebooted a couple of days ago and was dumped into a console login screen.        Looking at the current `syslog` I find now that there's no mention of either `gdm3` or `GNOME Display manager`, which were present in previous `syslog`'s.      Here's a few lines indicating where today's `syslog` deviates from an earlier one when things worked.    I've selected from the point where `gdm` first showed up in the version that worked.

This is my current version

```
Jan 15 17:43:06 5540 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jan 15 17:43:06 5540 kernel: [    0.058193] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
Jan 15 17:43:06 5540 kernel: [    0.058227] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
Jan 15 17:43:06 5540 kernel: [    0.058228] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
Jan 15 17:43:06 5540 kernel: [    0.058263] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
Jan 15 17:43:06 5540 systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Jan 15 17:43:06 5540 kernel: [    0.058849] ACPI: Enabled 10 GPEs in block 00 to 7F
Jan 15 17:43:06 5540 kernel: [    0.060272] ACPI: Power Resource [PG00] (on)
Jan 15 17:43:06 5540 kernel: [    0.062955] ACPI: Power Resource [WRST] (on)
```

Here's a snippet from the previous version, starting from a common line,   when things worked:

```
Jan 11 09:03:41 5540 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jan 11 09:03:41 5540 anacron[21939]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-01-11
Jan 11 09:03:41 5540 anacron[21939]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jan 11 09:04:21 5540 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[15604]: [FVWM_SMDEBUG] Saving /home/simon/.fvwm/.fs-restart-5540:0
```

It seems that now, the startup script isn't even looking for `gdm`

Could anybody advise, please, what might have gone awry?     I doubt if this could be related, but before the problem arose, `gmail` had slowed down to such an extent that when typing a simple email, I had to wait for about a minute for it to register my input.

Thanks for any help!