# ubuntu 20.04 missing /usr/sbin/gdm3 and /lib/systemd/system/gdm.service

Tags: boot, gnome, login-screen, gdm

This is a followup to my [earlier posting on this site.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308443/gnome-desktop-manager-no-longer-opening-drop-to-console-login-screen)    I have two different Dell machines running 20.04.    Both worked fine, and then, for no apparent reason, when I rebooted,  I could not get to the GNOME login screen.        It appears that the problem is related on both machines:   the files `/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service`, the link `/lib/systemd/system/gdm3` and `/usr/sbin/gdm3` are all missing, which certainly would at least partially explain my problem.     I tried copying both files from a third, working version of 20.04, then `sudo systemctl restart gdm` but no success.         Could somebody please explain why this is happening?    How could these files be being destroyed on reboot?  Obviously the common feature is my local home directory.      And secondly, what I can do to fix the problem?      I could of course rebuild, but it's obviously going to happen again.

Comment: Hey I just happen to get the same issue with 20.04 on Dell machine ! How did you figured out the problem ?